# AngularJs ngModel value is duplicated when input number by using Microsoft IME Japanese

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, ime, angular-ngmodel

I have a problem with Japanese number. When input by IME, ngModel is duplicated.

- My purpose: catch event when ngModel is changed, remove non-digit characters then format the result to render using ngModel.$viewValue and return filtered string to ngModel.
- Problem: When input number by MS IME (Hiragana), ngModel is duplicated.
- Ex: Input 300 => ngModel = 300300
- My investigation: Input 300 => $parser fired => set $viewValue = 300, return 300 to ngModel => ngModel.$render() => html is changed to 300 (good until now) => something wrong happned => ngModel changes to 300300 => $parser fired again...

This is the first time i work with Japanese so i currently have no idea why it happens. I'm looking for your experience about this problem.

```
ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(inputValue){
     var digits = String(inputValue).split('').filter(function (s) { return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' '); }).join('');

     ngModel.$viewValue = digits;
     ngModel.$render();

     return digits;
});
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/x0ervzr2/

*Note: On jsfiddle i can't input by IME (maybe its disabled?)

- On my computer: when i input there is a underline under text then i have to enter or focus out to apply value to textbox
- Side question: How can i prevent user input number by IME? (Google Chrome)

Thank you.

Comment: I end up with this code:
`$(element).attr('type', 'tel');`

This one will inactive IME when textbox is focused. I want to disable IME but google chrome doesn't support that yet :(, hope one day it will.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting element value via JavaScript, while IME also attempts to set it when composition finish. The actual behavior differ per browser. Google Chrome accepts your JS value (300) and IME value (300) together, that's where the 300300 comes.

You can test this behavior with jsfiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/bootleq/x14w3Lts/4/embedded/result/

A workaround is to use `setTimeout` to delay your JS setter execution later to IME compositionend, as demonstrated in the fiddle.

And there would be nothing wrong in angular or jsfiddle, without doing `$render` in angular $parsers function, everything works fine.